# Change background color of UIkit checkbox

Tags: html, css

**Question:**

How can I change the color of an UIkit icon? Specifically, I want to change the background color of the check box icon.

Here's a link to the [UIkit Form documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/form).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/css/uikit.min.css" />
<input style="color:red" class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

I want to change the color of the background.

Comment: `background: red;` instead of `color:red`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input.uk-checkbox {
background-color: red;
}

input.uk-checkbox:checked {
background-color: red;
}

input.uk-checkbox:checked:focus {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/css/uikit.min.css" />
<input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

> Because the UIkit applies styling using their framework you wil have
>   to overwrite.

So they use `.uk-checkbox {background-color: red;}`, just target from the input as above , `input.uk-checkbox {background-color: red;}`.